# "Could not find `npm` command. Is npm installed?" when starting nide

Tags: node.js, npm

Install nide use "npm install -g nide" successfully. After that, type "nide init" to start nide and initialize a new project, there is error message: "Could not find `npm` command. Is npm installed?"

I installed the nide using npm, and I'm sure that the npm is in the PATH. How can it ask me "Is npm installed" ?

Comment: I'd not be surprised if it's a bug of nide. [It has not been updated in the last 2 years](https://npmjs.org/package/nide).

Comment: Same problem for me. Looks like Node v0.10 breaks nide.

Comment: Can you show the output of ‘which npm’ and ‘npm -v’